# Call function onEdit of a cell value if value equals specific text

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function called copy() which can copy a range from a sheet and paste to another sheet. That function needs to be executed from script editor but I want to do it automatically if I change the value of cell Sheet3!A3.

With the following code, I can send the date/time to a specific cell. I want something like this which will just call the function copy() if the value of A3 of Sheet3 is changed.

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var range = event.range;
  //var cofCellEdited = range.getActivelumnOSheet();
  var cofCellEdited = range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  if (cofCellEdited === "Sale") {

    var timezone = "GMT+06:00"
    var timestamp_format = "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
    var updateColName = "Product";
    var timeStampColName = "Time";
    var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sale'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.
    var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
    var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName);
    updateCol = updateCol + 1;
    if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
      var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
      cell.setValue(date);
    }
  }
```

And my copy function is :

```js
function copy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1I9KYJUtT2Vi0yAi_b8LaBSijReL-XEoKKZUqTxeWmQQ");
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Suposed Share");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Payable");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A2:D3");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A" + (last_row + 1) + ":D" + (last_row + 1));
  source_range.copyTo(target_range, {
    contentsOnly: true
  });


}
```

How can I call this function if I change the value of Sheet3!A3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your request using [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) with the following formula in your code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A3' && e.source.getSheetName() == 'Sheet3') {
    copy();
  }
}
```

That formula will use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) to call the `copy()` formula every time that the cell `A3` of the sheet `Sheet3` is called. You don't need the `onEdit(event)` (from your question) in your code to make this work. Please, ask for help if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your short and elegant solution.It's working nicely so far. I've changed the function name because I need onEdit(event) for another purpose will it cause any problem in future? And May I know the difference between onEdit(e) and onEdit(event)?

Comment: You are welcome @ImtiazSiddique, I am happy that this code helped you. Changing the event object name from `e` to `event` won't give you troubles. `e` is the typical name for that object, but you can call it as you want; you just have to remember to change the name everywhere on the code. As a additional tip, if you have more that one function called `onEdit`, every one of them will run.